# Searching through multiple index yielding 0 documents in elasticsearch-py

Tags: python, elasticsearch, indexing, elasticsearch-py

I have a search query to make across multiple indexes. To enable this as per the [documentation](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html), I need to provide a comma-separated list of indexes.

[image]
But when I try to do it as: `es.search(index='index1,index2',body=body)`

I get no result:
`{u'hits': {u'hits': [], u'total': 0, u'max_score': None}, u'_shards': {u'successful': 10, u'failed': 0, u'skipped': 0, u'total': 10}, u'took': 1, u'timed_out': False}`

However, index='_all' works to search across all index. Am I doing something incorrectly here or is there some issue with this functionality? Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

According to the documentation posted by you:

- **index** a comma separated *list*... (enphasys is mine)

In your code you pass a string:

```
es.search(index='index1,index2',body=body)
```

So you should simply:

```
es.search(index=['index1','index2'],body=body)
```